# How to get users activity and status using discord api in python

Tags: python, discord

I want to get someone's activity and status using their id and discord api in python and I have written some code to do that but I'm really confused about the output.

The code:

```py
import requests
token = 'REDACTED'
headers = {'Authorization': token}
base_URL = "https://discord.com/api/v9"
base_URL_attachment = base_URL + "/activities"
f = requests.get(base_URL_attachment, headers=headers).json()
print(f)
```

The output:

```py
[{'user_id': '455082161050222595', 'application_id': '356876176465199104', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T17:50:26.457000+00:00', 'duration': 11062}, {'user_id': '455082161050222595', 'application_id': '614454657753939987', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T19:21:05.516000+00:00', 'duration': 74}, {'user_id': '911382588587921439', 'application_id': '356869127241072640', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T17:08:27.673000+00:00', 'duration': 20095}, {'user_id': '911382588587921439', 'application_id': '363412841862266880', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T21:14:12.069000+00:00', 'duration': 5399}, {'user_id': '324477408717701121', 'application_id': '363445589247131668', 'updated_at': '2022-09-02T15:28:11.245000+00:00', 'duration': 1510}, {'user_id': '237598665122775040', 'application_id': '356869127241072640', 'updated_at': '2022-09-02T08:34:11.834000+00:00', 'duration': 2818}, {'user_id': '720754227848151070', 'application_id': '356877880938070016', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T23:01:28.132000+00:00', 'duration': 0}, {'user_id': '720754227848151070', 'application_id': '357607478105604096', 'updated_at': '2022-09-04T01:38:28.368000+00:00', 'duration': 3600}, {'user_id': '995433254595330090', 'application_id': '432980957394370572', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T21:34:18.138000+00:00', 'duration': 594}, {'user_id': '821376098104377424', 'application_id': '363445589247131668', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T22:02:44.429000+00:00', 'duration': 10293}]
```

Maybe my code isn't even doing what I actually want it to do, Maybe I'm just doing this completely incorrect and the output is something way different, Any help would be appreciated.

I did see another post with something similar and the answer was this link https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object-activity-structure now I don't understand how to like implement this since I tried and it failed supposedly the data is supposed to look like this if I implemented it: { "details": "24H RL Stream for Charity", "state": "Rocket League", "name": "Twitch", "type": 1, "url": "twitch.tv/discord" }

Answer (score 0):

The response is JSON. See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp.

The response looks valid so I'm not sure what help you need. Please review.

```
[
     {
          'user_id': '455082161050222595', 
          'application_id': '356876176465199104', 
          'updated_at': '2022-09-03T17:50:26.457000+00:00', 
          'duration': 11062},
...]
```

---

One of the things that I often do is load JSON data into a Pandas DataFrame which then makes it easy to do further analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

response_string = {'user_id': '455082161050222595', 'application_id': '356876176465199104', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T17:50:26.457000+00:00', 'duration': 11062}, {'user_id': '455082161050222595', 'application_id': '614454657753939987', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T19:21:05.516000+00:00', 'duration': 74}, {'user_id': '911382588587921439', 'application_id': '356869127241072640', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T17:08:27.673000+00:00', 'duration': 20095}, {'user_id': '911382588587921439', 'application_id': '363412841862266880', 'updated_at': '2022-09-03T21:14:12.069000+00:00', 'duration': 5399}

x = json.dumps(response_string)
y = json.loads(x)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(y)
```

Comment: Im just confused because the response occurs even when everyone in my friend's list is offline and i also wanna be able to specify ids, and some application ids arent in the verified games list for discord https://gist.github.com/Cynosphere/c1e77f77f0e565ddaac2822977961e76?permalink_comment_id=3646931 such as valorant

Comment: I did see another post with something similar and the answer was this link https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#activity-object-activity-structure now i dont understand how to like implement this since i tried and it failed supposedly the data is supposed to look like this if i implemented it:
{
  "details": "24H RL Stream for Charity",
  "state": "Rocket League",
  "name": "Twitch",
  "type": 1,
  "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/discord"
}

Comment: I haven't used Discord APIs before. Since you are getting a valid JSON response, if the repsonse isn't what you are expecting then it's most likely either (a) you haven't structured your request properly (e.g. where you specify the user you are querying and the timerange, etc), or (b) you are hitting the wrong API end-point (e.g. you are querying GetUser instead of GetUserActivity).